# How to switch from tailwind CSS Play CDN to production build?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS Play CDN for local development, and would like to use PostCSS to build a production version

Basically every time I need to manually replace the following line in `index.html`

`<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

with

`<link href="/dist/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

before pushing to production site

What is the best way to do that automatically each time I publish the website?

Answer (score 1):

Quotes from [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn)

> Use the Play CDN to try Tailwind right in the browser without any build step. The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only, and is not the best choice for production.

So you need to use build tools like `webpack`, `Rollup`, `Vite`, and `Parcel`

- [Tailwind CSS with Parcel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/parcel)
- [Using Postcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

Comment: I know how to build tailwind css for production with PostCSS.  But my question is how to automatically replace the Play CDN with production build CSS in the ```index.html``` file each time I push my code from local development to production site.

Comment: @CoolMoon are you using any framework or only html? Technologically I just need to import tailwind directives into my root css file and embed in html then no need to replace build file

Comment: No, I am not using any framework, just plain html file.  Basically I just use Play CDN on development (without any other CSS file), and not using ```npm run dev``` in local machine.  It builds the CSS file on production server with PostCSS when I push the code there before publishing the website.  So essentially no other CSS file in local machine, and only the complied css file on production server

Comment: **no other CSS** can use `style` tag instead. Basically just use build tools on dev and push it to server build and serves the `dist` folder of build I think

Comment: Is anyone can tell me WHY cdn is best choice for production? Can I still use it?

Comment: @JinLim docs say "The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only, and is not the best choice for production"

Comment: @nosnart , then WHY is NOT the best choice?

Comment: @JinLim I think using CDN will import all classes of tailwind into your site and not purge unused classes which increase bundled size of your web

Comment: @nosnart Even all classes are not that big sizes. is that only downside of CDN?

Comment: @JinLim idk well about it. Possibly you could find more helpful information about using CDN on tailwind docs or their github repo ^^

Comment: to answer more specifically why not use CDN in production, the Play CDN will add about 500kb of JavaScript to your page load which could be significcant on slow connection; during this time your styles also won't render which means the page may look broken until that JS downloads.   Finally, after the script executes it will do another network request for another xx or xxx KB of CSS depending on how much your page needs.   By comparison to a build no extra JS is downloaded & your styles include on initial page load so will be a much better experience for users on slow connection.

Comment: @Derrick, CDN JS isn't 500KB but 362KB uncompressed and 110KB compressed, and 110KB isn't meant to impact page load.

Unless you intentionally put "async" or "defer", the JS download WILL block the rest of the HTML from being parsed, so it doesn't render the page broken.

Comment: However, it does render the page broken on Safari (at least on version 16.6 as I tested) when the page gets big as Safari seems to struggle having Tailwind parse the entire page to generate the CSS before the page is displayed and for a split second, the page is shown with no Tailwind CSS applied.

But this can be fixed easily by writing `<style>.block {display: none}</style>` right above the Tailwind CDN script tag, and provide `block` class name to the body tag, which will hide the page content right until Tailwind CSS is applied, overriding `block` class with `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

A serverside language to render your page is a good option here since you could simply replace that one line with a variable that would render the line for your CDN or your build depending on if say `production=true`

For example, in NodeJS you could use a template engine like [EJS](https://ejs.co/)
or here is an even simpler solution using only template literals:

```
const production = false 
const twCdn = `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`
const build = <link href="/dist/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`
const html = `<html>
${ production ? cdn : build } 
<body>
  <h1 class="bg-green-500">hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>`

//... setup a server such as Express and serve 
//the html var as a route ex: 

expressApp.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send(html))
```

alternatively if you didn't want to use a dynamic server directly you could write a script in any language of your choice to perform a replacement directly in your hello.html file (or whatever name it is) ie- run after your PostCSS build script.  In the case of NodeJs again, here you could use [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api) which lets you use the jQuery API headless:

Ex:

```
const fs = require('fs') 
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
//import the dev page: 
const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/hello.html'))

//perform the swap: 
$('head').append('<link href="/dist/main.css" rel="stylesheet">') 
$('script[src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"]').remove() 

//overwrite the page, now prod ready: 
fs.writeFileSync( __dirname + '/hello.html', $.html(), 'utf8' )
```